# Showing Circular indeterminate Progress on button click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a button that when clicked runs some code that imports data from another website. What would be nice is to have a Circular indeterminate indicator (Material UI) that shows the import is in progress, until completion.

My code below shows the code I am running and some of the jsx.

```
<Box mt={5} mb={5} width={1200}>
            <Grid
              container
              justify="center"
              spacing={2}
              style={{ padding: '25px' }}
            >
              <Grid item xs={7}>
                <Typography variant="h3" style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>
                 List
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5" style={{ marginTop: '2em' }}>
                  some text
                </Typography>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  size="large"
                  style={{ marginTop: '1em' }}
                  // style={{ maxWidth: '108px', minWidth: '108px' }}
                  onClick={() => {
                    let arrCollection = [];
                    const stream = fetch(
                      'https://othersite.org/api/games/user/neio',
                      { headers: { Accept: 'application/x-ndjson' } }
                    );

                    const onMessage = obj => {
                      arrCollection.push(obj);
                    };

                    const onComplete = () =>
                      console.log('The stream has completed');

                    stream.then(readStream(onMessage)).then(onComplete);

                    console.log('arrCollection', arrCollection);
                  }}
                >
                  Import Games
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
```

What I can't work out is how to display the "circular indeterminate" while importing and then show it completed.

This is the link to the circular indeterminate code: https://material-ui.com/components/progress/

Do I need to add a node to the Dom or something?

Comment: Can't you just use the state variable? when the onClick function starts set it to true and when that finishes, set it to false. Then toggle your UI on the basis of that variable.

Comment: You were right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already, you can use state to manage this.
Something like this should work

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  <div>{loading ? <LoadingIndicator /> : ''}</div>
  <Button
    onClick={() => {
      setLoading(true);

      let arrCollection = [];
      const stream = fetch('https://othersite.org/api/games/user/neio', {
        headers: { Accept: 'application/x-ndjson' },
      });

      const onMessage = (obj) => {
        arrCollection.push(obj);
      };

      const onComplete = () => console.log('The stream has completed');

      stream.then(readStream(onMessage)).then(onComplete);

      console.log('arrCollection', arrCollection);

      setLoading(false);
    }}
  >
    Import Games
  </Button>
```

Comment: I had already worked it out by now, but your answer is the type of thing I did, thank you.